# Voltage sense activated by arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, components

I'm interested in making the following resistor-divider circuit where I can tell 'POLL' to be high by my Arduino and then sample the voltage reading. The battery will have anywhere from 6-10volts. I have quite a few 2N2222A's on hand and I was wondering if I could use it as Q1 as the voltage specification says 40v 500mA (I don't expect a load to be on this), similarly, I was wondering if I could use [J176](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1200000-1299999/001264456-da-01-en-JFET_P_CH_30V_350M_J176_D74Z_TO_92_3_FSC.pdf) as M1 or if there are other options? Due to size constraints I'm trying to use all TO-92 packages.

[image: Schematic]

[J176](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1200000-1299999/001264456-da-01-en-JFET_P_CH_30V_350M_J176_D74Z_TO_92_3_FSC.pdf):

> This device is designed for low level analog switching sample and hold
>   circuits and chopper stabilized amplifiers.

Comment: What's the reason for not just using 2 resistors?

Comment: This way the resistor-divider turned on when in use to minimize battery loss. It only needs to be polled every minute or so...

Comment: Ok, but is this really worth it, to save 250uA? (10V / 40kOhm)

Comment: @WesleyLee well, it is a battery, so almost surely yes it is worth it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany -- I mean, if he is using Arduino there are many easier ways of saving much more energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2N2222 is fine, but the J176 is a p-channel JFET and not what you want (it will be 'on' all the time in this circuit- until you turn the 2N2222 on, after which it and the 2N2222 will both be fried).

Try a [BSS84](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BS/BSS84.pdf) for the p-channel MOSFET, or maybe a [BS250](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/BS250P.pdf) if you insist on using bulky through-hole parts.

The datasheet for the J176 is a little remiss in not telling you exactly what it is or using a schematic symbol anywhere at all.

Comment: don't make fun of through-hole... they are easy to solder! ;)

Comment: @Alex Available choices will be **severely** constrained if you limit yourself to through-hole, in many cases.

Comment: understandable, I just don't have the necessary equipment to micro solder